# Fody Costura and embedding PDBs

Tags: fody-costura

So, I've got a small console app and I've used Fody/Costura to embed all referenced dlls into it

So far so good.

The docs for Costura says that it'll also embed the PDBs into the exe, and it appears to do that.

BUT...

If I force an exception in the app and check the stack trace, the method names are there, but there is no line number information in the stack frames, which leads me to believe that iether the embedding didn't actually work, or that .net is not picking up the embedded PDB when a fault occurs and the stack trace is rendered.

Anyone have any ideas if this is even supposed to work the way I'm imagining it should?